# c++ sending ascii 254 through serial communication

Tags: c++, serial-port, ascii

I'm using the Serial.cpp code from Arduino's website.

What I'm doing right now is using the R220HPRS Relay Switch. The problem is that the sample codes are in VB and I'm using c++. So, I read through the manual and found that by sending ASCII 254 and ASCII 1 will turn Relay 1 switch to on

VB Example

```
  MSComm1.Output = Chr$(254) 'Enter Command Mode 
  MSComm1.Output = Chr$(1) 'Turn On Relay 1
```

Then I found the Serial.cpp from Arduino's website and decided to try using it.
And when I did, I got connect with the device (or it said it did when I ran the program), but I don't know as to how to send ASCII 254 and ASCII 1

Here's the code
From Serial.cpp

```
bool Serial::WriteData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    DWORD bytesSend;

    //Try to write the buffer on the Serial port
    if(!WriteFile(this->hSerial, (void *)buffer, nbChar, &bytesSend, 0))
    {
        //In case it don't work get comm error and return false
        ClearCommError(this->hSerial, &this->errors, &this->status);

        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Main

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Welcome to the serial test app!\n\n");

Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM3");    // adjust as needed

if (SP->IsConnected())
    printf("We're connected");

while(SP->IsConnected())
{
    char *chr0 = "254";
    SP->WriteData(chr0, 1); 
    SP->WriteData(chr0, 1);
    Sleep(500);
}
return 0;
}
```

I know chr0 = "254" is not ASCII, but I don't have any idea how to send ASCII 254 and ASCII 1.

Answer (score 4):

To send a single `char` with the value 245, you need to make it a char:

```
char chr0 = 254; 

SP->WriteData(&chr0, 1);
```

Comment: Just to be safe, shouldn't `chr0`  be `unsigned`  to avoid overflow?

Comment: Probably, but that would mean copying and pasting ALL the code to change ALL the char to unsigned, and I'm too lazy to do that - it's unlikely to cause an issue on a Windows system - and WreiteFile is a windows call...

Answer (score 0):

```
char *chr0, you are pointing to a sting.
it should be char ch = 254;
and then send the address of ch.
```

Remember Single Quote for Single Character!!!